# OSError: [WinError 10038] An attempt was made to perform an operation on an element that is not a socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Good afternoon.

I have the following problem:

I am implementing a client server system that allows sending messages and files, when the client sends the message files the server will send the img folder with its files.

The problem happens that when the files finish arriving to the client I cannot send a new message to the server since the following error appears:

```
> hi
> hello
> files
Receiving folder img
Receiving Captura.PNG size 52120
Receiving Captura2.PNG size 140060
Receiving Thumbs.db size 36864
> new
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C: \ Users \ Dell \ Desktop \ client.py", line 9, in <module>
     client.sendall (msg.encode ())
OSError: [WinError 10038] An attempt was made to perform an operation on an element that is not a socket
```

What I expected is that once the file transmission is finished they will continue to send messages to each other and that only if the client sent the exit message will the server end

**CLient**

```
import socket
import os

client = socket.socket()
client.connect(('192.168.8.4',5555))

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    client.sendall(msg.encode())
    if msg == "files":
        with client,client.makefile('rb') as newfile:
            Folder = newfile.readline()
            if not Folder:
                break
            Folder = Folder.strip().decode()
            NoFiles = int(newfile.readline())
            print("Receiving folder {}".format(Folder))
            os.makedirs(Folder,exist_ok=True)
            for file in range(NoFiles):
                filename = newfile.readline().strip().decode()
                filesize = int(newfile.readline())
                data = newfile.read(filesize)
                print("Receiving {} size {}".format(filename,filesize))
                with open(os.path.join(Folder,filename),"wb") as f:
                    f.write(data)
```

**Server**

```
import socket
import os

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(("192.168.8.4",5555))
server.listen(2)

FolderName = "img"
Path = "C:\\Users\\AngelHp\\Desktop\\img"

while True:
    client,address = server.accept()
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(1024).decode()
        print(msg)
        if msg == "files":
            print("Sending  {}".format(FolderName))
            client.sendall(FolderName.encode()+b'\n')
            Files = os.listdir(Path)
            client.sendall(str(len(Files)).encode()+b'\n')
            for File in Files:
                pathfile = os.path.join(Path,File)
                filesize = os.path.getsize(pathfile)
                print("Sending {} size {}".format(pathfile,filesize))
                client.sendall(File.encode()+b'\n')
                client.sendall(str(filesize).encode()+b'\n')
                with open(pathfile,'rb') as f:
                    client.sendall(f.read())
        elif msg == "exit":
           break
```

Comment: Based on the description of the with statement (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), I suspect that because you have "client" as one of the with-items, the socket is being closed implicitly when the with block completes.

Comment: @DaveCosta,Then I leave it like this:`with client.makefile ('rb') as newfile:`

Comment: That's what I would try.

Comment: @DaveCosta,that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded from comment to answer:

Based on the description of the with statement (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), I suspect that because you have `client` as one of the with-items, the socket is being closed implicitly when the with block completes.

Dispensing with the technical jargon from the question, when an object is used in a `with` statement, it will be automatically cleaned up / closed / whatever when the `with` block ends.  In this case, that meant that the socket reference was no longer valid on the next loop iteration, causing the error.

Since there seems to be no reason to include `client` in the with statement, I would just remove it.